# Using ARPACK with PARDISO

Tags: numerical-methods, pardiso

This is a question similar to [a question here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/66511/).

I wonder is there already an open source  implementation or example of [ARPACK Eigensolver](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/UG/ug.html) that works well with [PARDISO solver](http://www.pardiso-project.org/) and [Intel mkl](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl/) library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented it already, in C#.

The idea is that one must convert the matrix format in [CSR format](http://www.intel.com/software/products/mkl/docs/webhelp/appendices/mkl_appA_SMSF.html). Then, one can use MKL to compute linear equation solving algorithm ( using pardiso solver), the matrix-vector manipulation.